# LINQ Spliting string into substrings sequentially, with using a delimiter

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I  have a table of strings, e.g :

```
string[] list = { "900 google.mail.com", "50 yahoo.com", "1 intel.mail.com", "5 wiki.org" };

string delimiter = ".";
foreach (var item in cpdomains)
{
    var result = item.Split(' ', '.').Aggregate((a,b) => a + delimiter +b);
    result.ForEach(e => Console.WriteLine(e));
    Console.WriteLine(result);        
}
```

my result now

- 900.google.mail.com
- 50.yahoo.com
- 1.intel.mail.com
- 5.wiki.org

I want to split every string for substrings like this:

```
1- 900
2- google.mail.com
3-mail.com
4-com
etc...
```

How I can do this ?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you add a question also? What isn’t working? Errors? Wrong results?

Comment: I ve just added a question 

Comment: I still can’t see any...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    public string[] GetParentDomains(string[] input) {
    return input
        .SelectMany(s => s.Split(' '))
        .SelectMany(s => {
                    string[] splitDomain = s.Split('.');
                    return  Enumerable.Range(0, splitDomain.Length)
                        .Select(counter => 
                                String.Join(".", splitDomain.Skip(counter)))
                        .ToArray(); 
                   })
        .ToArray();              
}
```

Output

```
900
google.mail.com
mail.com
com
50
yahoo.com
com
1
intel.mail.com
mail.com
com
5
wiki.org
org
```